# Verbs and the subjects changing places

Tags: questions

I have problems with these structures:

Here I think both sentences are correct.

> 1a) You know it better than me.
>
> 1b) You know it better than I do.

---

In real life I hear mostly `a)`, but I think `b)` is more correct. Because the first clause shows that it is a question (*Do you know*) and that's enough.

> 2a) Do you know who is he? (Wrong but common)
>
> 2b) Do you know who he is?

Comment: 2a is characteristic of informal speech and only rarely appears in writing.  If I did transcribe someone speaking this way, I would put a comma after *do you know* to make it clear that it's an introductory clause, although this practice isn't universally observed.  (In speech, intonation makes the structure clear.)

Comment: @snailboat I think I'd be more likely to say "Who is he, do you know?" than 2a (though I do get what you mean about the intonation.) Perhaps this just isn't part of my dialect, though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We often omit the repeated words in parallel expressions.

If you said #1 in full, you would say, "You know it better than I know it." As "know it" is common to both parts, we often shorten this to "You know it better than I", or if this sounds too abrupt or we fear some ambiguity, we may say, "You know it better than I do."

"You know it better than me" is often said in informal speech, but is incorrect. "Me" is the objective case, the thing being acted on, while "I" is the subjective case, the thing doing the act. In this sentence, "I/me" am doing the acting -- I am knowing something -- so we should use "I". Technically, in "you know it better than me", as "me" is an object, this must be the object of "know". That is, "You know it better than you know me." In this case it's very unlikely that that's what the writer meant.

But consider these two sentences: "Alice likes Bob more than I." And, "Alice likes Bob more than me." The first sentence means that Alice likes Bob more than I like Bob. I might say this if I see that Alice likes Bob but I don't like him, maybe I'm about to warn her that he's a bad person. The second sentence means that Alice likes Bob more than she likes me. I might say this if I am jealous that she is showing favoritism to Bob over me. Maybe I want to be her boyfriend but she prefers Bob and my feelings are hurt.

Comment: What about this usage? -- "This was created by students *like me*." Should it be *like I am*?

Comment: @Graduate Yes, your example is correct, and "You know it better than me" is, too.  Jay's ellipsis analysis is referring to a rule that was inaccurate when it was made up a couple centuries ago, and it hasn't become any more accurate in the meantime.

Comment: There's some additional discussion on [Arnold Zwicky's blog](http://arnoldzwicky.org/2012/01/23/dinosaur-grammar/).

Comment: @snailboat That more and more people *today* say: "you know it better than me" is very true. Grammar rules change more slowly than people's speech in modern life. However, I'm not so sure that the rule you are mentioning was made up "centuries ago" and that it became fossilized. As recently as the 1970s the rule was accepted and taught to children and adults alike. I myself will say: "He sings better than I do" because of the subject, he, used with the verb. Using the object pronoun at the beginning of a sentence sounds goddamn awful: "Him (me) sings better than me (him)"

Comment: Whereas, "He is taller than me" sounds less stuffy than "He is taller than I (am)." I believe that English teachers would be less likely to correct their (native speaking) pupils writing containing instances  of the latter, but their red pens would start quivering over the former i.e.; *subject + verb + comparative adjective + than + object pronoun*.

Comment: @Mari-LouA According to the MWDEU, usage was split about 50/50 between the two options in the 18th century, so yes, the rule was wrong even when it was made up a little over a couple centuries ago; the analogy to Latin was broken rather than strained, as usual.

Comment: @snailboat  If usage was split 50/50, and many people still follow this pattern in speech and writing today, why do you insist on saying it is wrong? Grammar is not science, it's about trying to make sense of something which often has no sense. What would you say to this construction: He sings "Love me do" better than I sing "She loves you".

Comment: Because the supposed rule says that one of the options is wrong, which it wasn't and still isn't, so it can't possibly be a real rule.

Comment: Would you consider my sentence above as being acceptable?

Comment: We've gotten into these arguments before about what constitutes a "real" or "valid" grammar rule. I agree that the fact that somebody wrote a rule on a piece of paper 100 years ago does not make it so. But I reject the idea that if you can guess what the speaker probably meant that the sentence is valid, or if you can find a few hundred people who, when chatting informally among their friends, say something, that by definition makes it right. I think the correct test is a combination of, (a) what do a large majority of educated people say or write?, and (b) what is logical and consistent?

Comment: ...  "You know it better than me" fails rule (b), as I believe the example I gave demonstrates: it creates an ambiguity that is easily avoided by following the rule I quote. Thus I stand by my original assertion.

Comment: Not to be argumentative, but: "Because the supposed rule says that one of the options is wrong, which it wasn't and still isn't, so it can't possibly be a real rule." Well, this is a circular argument. "You say that x is invalid because it violates the rule, but that isn't a real rule, because if it was a real rule, then x would be invalid, which it isn't." Of course if we don't accept the premise that x is valid, then the rule may very well be real.

Comment: @Jay Context.  I was responding to "[since] many people still follow this pattern in speech and writing today, why do you insist on saying it is wrong", explaining that it was a prescription against one of the correct forms, rather than an acceptance of a valid form.  The actual reason it's invalid is that it has never described standard English usage, whether in the 18th, 19th, 20th, or 21st centuries.  Of course, if you believe it doesn't matter whether or not the rule correctly describes the standard English language, then you can advocate for nonsense like the "no split infinitives" rule.

Answer (score 1):

1b) You know it better than I do.

If you strictly follow the grammar, this one is correct. After the conjunction "than", almost all repetitive words are omitted. This is called "obligatory reduction" and seen in sentences using "as" for comparative description.

It's also correct to say "You know it better than I."

Strictly speaking, 1a) is not correct grammatically, but it is acceptable as colloquial expression. However, it could be confusing because you may think "it is better than I (me), not you in the sentence. Whether it happens or not depends on the context.

2a) Do you know who is he? (Wrong but common)

2b) Do you know who he is?

After "do you know", you do not use an interrogative sentence structure. In your case, "who" comes first, but a phrase having a declarative sentence structure follows.

If the question is "who is he?", you say "Do you know who he is?

But "Do you know who is he?" is not wrong grammatically when the "he" is a complement of the verb "is". This depends on what you ask.

---

I think I need to modify my description.
I said "You know it better than me" was grammatically wrong for comparison between you and I. This is reasonable when the "than" is a conjunction. But "than" can be a preposition. In this case, "You know it better than me" should be OK.

"Then" as a preposition may be established from such misuse, I just speculate though.